# Made one apk, installed two apps

Tags: android

I made an android app with External library. But I don't know why, when I install my apk(only one), installed two apps. One is mine and the other one is an example project of the external library. I think when I started my app, I had to understand how the library works, so I put that example project in my project.

But I can't find the example library's activity or layout somethings, and I don't know **where to delete the settings of install example library.** It seems like ghost...

Comment: You should provide your external library's `AndroidManifest.xml`, before that, you can check `AndroidManifest.xml` and remove ```<intent-filter>
   <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>```

Comment: @quanlit it worked! you saved my day. Thank you

Comment: @quanlt You should convert your comment to an answer, so that the OP can accept it and the post will be removed from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: you're right @KlingKlang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check `AndroidManifest.xml` in your 3rd library and remove
`<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>`